# problems JSSOR Slider

Tags: safari, jssor

I have a big problem with jssor Slider I made a gallery with more photos when access from iphone 4 safari crashing only iphone 4. On iphone 5 I don't have this problem.

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth)
        jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 960));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider(); // Here is the problem when the page loading...

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

Comment: How many photos are there? Any url can I access online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to reduce the impact, please kindly have a try.

## 1. Set $AutoPlay option to false and then make it auto play by api call (jssor_slider2.$Play();) after the first scale.

```
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider2.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth)
        jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 960));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider(); // Here is the problem when the page loading...
jssor_slider2.$Play();

$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

## 2. Set $HWA option to false to disable hardware acceleration.

## 3. Define image in lazy loading format to reduce loading at the beginning.

```
<div><img src2="url" /></div>
```